# Is there a way to add a byte to the beginning of TIdBytes variable in delphi without a loop?

Tags: delphi, arrays

I have a TIdBytes variable myBytesArray and I'd like to add a byte to its beginning. I tried with a loop (although I'd definitely prefer a non-loop solution), but it still didn't work :

```
myBytesArray : TIdBytes;
// ...
len := Length(myBytesArray);
SetLength(myBytesArray, len + 1);
for i := len downto 1 do begin
  myBytesArray[i] := myBytesArray[i-1];
end;
myBytesArray[0] := myNewByte;
```

Comment: Check [System.Move](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/System.Move)

Comment: Note that System.Move still contains a loop though; it's just hidden as part of the implementation.  There isn't a way to add a byte without copying all of the other data one way or the other.

Comment: The answer is to use Move as David Heffernan has shown.  That being said, I think your loop should've been for I := Len+1 downto 1 do myBytesArray[I] := myBytesArray[I-1];  As your code stands, you're copying the same byte over and over.

Comment: @David loop must be len downto 1

Comment: @David Heffernan:  D'oh!  You're right of course.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`TIdBytes` is an Indy data type.  Indy has many functions in the `IdGlobal` unit for manipulating `TIdBytes`, such as `InsertByte()`:

```
InsertByte(myBytesArray, myNewByte, 0);
```

Comment: Well, yes - both your answer and David's are correct - thanks a lot for the quick response guys, but as you said - InsertByte is the best answer for my question :)

Comment: And in the end this routine does not much more than a downto loop to shift the bytes. Refactoring (extract method) of your posted code would have done the same. Also InsertByte calls ExpandBytes which does things that are not necessary for InsertByte if you want to be as fast as possible. @Remy You could make InsertByte a one liner by passing AByte to ExpandBytes.

Comment: Roman's question wasn't about speed/efficientcy, just how to insert without looping manually. But thanks for the tip about `ExpandBytes()`, it has been checked in.

Answer (score 5):

You can fix your loop by using index `i` rather than `len`:

```
for i := len downto 1 do 
  myBytesArray[i] := myBytesArray[i-1];
```

Your code copies the byte at `len` every time.

However, you can write a version without a loop using the `Move` procedure like this:

```
SetLength(myBytesArray, len + 1);
if len > 0 then
  Move(myBytesArray[0], myBytesArray[1], len);
myBytesArray[0] := myNewByte;
```

The `if` statement is needed if range checking is enabled.

As Remy says, the `IdGlobal` unit already provides the functionality that you need with the `InsertByte` procedure.

```
InsertByte(myBytesArray, myNewByte, 0);
```

Comment: I was just testing something really similar to what you wrote - all the credit goes to you for the quick and correct answer :)

Comment: Although this answer is technically accurate, it is not the "correct" solution, as Indy provides its own `InsertByte()` function for inserting a byte into a `TIdBytes` at a given index.